# Optimal Poincaré constants under combined boundary and average conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ be the unit square, $\Gamma_1=[0,1]\times\{0;1\}$ its horizontal boundary and  $\Gamma_2= \{0;1\}\times[0,1]$ its vertical boundary.

I would like to know the *optimal* Poincaré constants $C$, defined by
$$
\forall u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)\quad \int_\Omega u^2\le C\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2,
$$

under these conditions (separately):

i) $u|_{\Gamma_1}=0$;

ii)  $u|_{\Gamma_1}=0$ *and* $u$ has zero average: $\int_\Omega u=0 $.

*Updated part*:

I *presume* that in the first case the optimal constant is $1/\pi^2$, if I correctly interpreted the method for finding it (as eigenvalue of the laplacian), realized by the function $u(x,y)=\sin(\pi y) $. In the second case I think it could be $1/2\pi^2$, realized by $u(x,y)=\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi y) $.

iii) $u|_{\Gamma_1}=0$,  $u$ has zero average: $\int_\Omega u=0$ and $u$ is periodic at boundary $\Gamma_2$, i.e. $u(0,y)=u(1,y) $

In this case I guess the constant is $1/4\pi^2$, realized by $u(x,y)= \sin(2\pi y) $.

Comment: I think it's quite easy to show that (i) reduces to the one-dimensional case, so the constant is indeed $1/\pi^2$, and the optimal function is $u(x,y) = \sin(\pi y)$.  This is constant in $x$ and in particular periodic, which also answers your final question.

Comment: And a guess for (ii) would be that the constant is $1/4\pi^2$ and the optimizer is $u(x,y) = \sin(2\pi y)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. i) is ok. In that case, we can say that the reduction to the 1D case provides at least an upper bound for the constant and I am happy with it. As for ii), your guess is a good candidate. I would need also a definitive evidence. Poincaré constants can be obtained as an eigenvalue of the Laplace operator (so sines are candidates) under suitable boundary conditions. I do not know how choose the conditions corresponding to the prescriptions ii) to reach a rigorous proof.